# Calculus- Converting equation from Cartesian to polar Cordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I'm having difficulties with the following equation to simplify it and converting to a polar form

$$y^2 - 3x^2 - 4x - 1 = 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos\theta\\{}\\y=r\sin\theta\end{cases}\implies y^2-3x^2-4x-1=0\;\mapsto r^2(\sin^2\theta-3\cos^2\theta)-4r\cos\theta-1=0$$

**Another way:**

$$0=y^2-3x^2-4x-1=y^2+x^2-4(x^2+x)-1\implies$$

$$x^2+y^2=4\left(x+\frac12\right)^2\stackrel{\text{polar coord.}}\implies r^2=4\left(r\cos\theta+\frac12\right)^2=4\frac{2r\cos\theta+1}2=4r\cos\theta+2$$

Comment: please edit your answer - there is a typo

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks for the answer, but you just replaced the x and y, in my textbook calculus its given the simplified form which is:r = 1 + 2r cosθ

Comment: @MahamadHusen Of course, but applying basic trigonometry identities, quadratic roots formula and etc.  is your job now

Comment: @DonAntonio so from the step the you gave, what i have to do?do i have to use trig identities ? my teacher says it need some simplification, i have tried so much, but couldnt done it!

Comment: @Mah This is what I'd begin to do: $$\sin^2\theta-3\cos^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta-3\cos^2\theta=1-4\cos^2\theta=(1+2\cos\theta)(1-2\cos\theta)\implies$$we have$$(1+2\cos\theta)(1-2\cos\theta)\,r^2-(4\cos\theta)\,r-1=0$$and this is a quadratic equation in $\;r\;$ , whose discriminant is$$\Delta=(4\cos\theta)^2-4(1+2\cos\theta)(1-2\cos\theta)\cdot(-1)=4$$so by the quadratic formula$$r_{1,2}=\frac{4\cos\theta\pm2}{2(1+2\cos\theta)(1-2\cos\theta)}=\frac{2\cos\theta\pm1}{(1+2\cos\theta)(1-2\cos\theta)}$$Try now to take it from here

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you so much! your "another way" was exactly what i was searching for! but can you just tell me two thing, what happened to the "-1". when you completed the square, shouldn't we ad the (b/2)^2 to the other side too? i think we have to add the 1/4 to the other side too!

Comment: @MahamadHusen $$4\left(x+\frac12\right)^2=4x^2+4x+1$$ There is the $\;-1\;$ from the other side which became $\;+1\;$ on that side...